# Application Processes "On Demand"-option missing (Oracle Apex)

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm using Oracle Database 12c + Application Express (Product Build 18.1).
[In the documentation for release 18.1](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-18.1/HTMDB/understanding-application-processes.htm#HTMDB-GUID-A36B9E6C-A5A4-4548-B1E7-18D5FD42A20C) you can find that while "Creating an Application Process" the option "Point" must have the value "On Demand".

> Point - Identify the point during the processing of each page in the application that this process would run. Note the option, **On Demand**, only runs when requested by a page process.

But I can't find this option:

[image: On Demand-option missing]

How can I create [an "On Demand" process](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-18.1/HTMDB/understanding-application-processes.htm#HTMDB29848)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An On-Demand Process is an Ajax Callback. It's just named differently in the real world than in the documentation.